# Dealing with zeros while iterating a model for percent change

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, error, python-parser

I'm using ArcGIS to examine some aquatic vegetation changes over time and I have created a model that adds two fields: Area_percentLoss and Biomass_percentLoss. My model is iterating over feature classes in a gdb (annual vegetation polygons). My calculate field for percent of biomass lost is

```
([BiomassLoss_kg]/[TotalBiomass_kg]) * 100
```

However, when it comes to a `BiomassLoss = 0` I get an error. How could I write a Python script that does something to the effect of:

```
Biomass_PercentLoss =

IF BiomassLoss = 0
THEN Biomass_PercentLoss = 0
ELSE Biomass_PercentLoss = ([BiomassLoss_kg]/[TotalBiomass_kg]) * 100
```

It's just dividing something by 0 is throwing an error, I think.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/ and it should make more sense.

Comment: If the problem is dividing by zero, you should probably be checking `IF TotalBiomass_kg = 0`

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Do you want to use the VBScript or Python Parser of the Calculate Field tool?  I would recommend the Python Parser.  What was your precise error message?

Comment: Thanks, all. Yes, I was mistaken about which field was 0 (TotalBiomass_kg). That's perfect. I should have mentioned that I wanted to use Python, which I did end up doing. And I'm using Arc 10.3. I'll remember that info for next time I post. Very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If the calc is `([BiomassLoss_kg]/[TotalBiomass_kg]) * 100` then it shouldn't fail on `BiomassLoss_kg = 0`, only on `TotalBiomass_kg = 0` (divide by zero error).

```py
def calc_biomass_pc_loss(bml, tbml):
    if bml == 0 or tbml == 0:
        pl = 0
    else:
        pl = (bml/tbml)*100
    return pl

calc_biomass_pc_loss( !BiomassLoss_kg!, !TotalBiomass_kg!)
```

[image]

You don't need to include the `bml==0` as the result in this case will always be `0` anyway.  I included it here because your question asked

> How could I write a Python script that does something to the effect
>   of:
>
> ```
> Biomass_PercentLoss =  
>
> IF BiomassLoss = 0 
> THEN Biomass_PercentLoss = 0  
> ELSE Biomass_PercentLoss = ([BiomassLoss_kg]/[TotalBiomass_kg]) * 100
> ```

but as `BiomassLoss = 0` isn't the problem it isn't actually required in the code.

Comment: Your comment and your code are incongruous, because there is no problem if `bml` is equal to 0, only if `tbml` is. I think a `try/except` clause is clearer, catching the [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ZeroDivisionError), and then making `pl` equal to 0 in that case.

Comment: I included the `bml==0` as that was what was asked.  It doesn't make any difference to the output total as zero divided by anything is still zero, so leaving it there makes it clear what will happen.